# How to login as krisv in jBPM5?

Tags: java, jboss, jbpm

The documentation says

> ```
> Open up the process management console:
> http://localhost:8080/jbpm-console
>
> Log in, using "krisv" / "krisv" as username / password.
> ```

however krisv is .... not a good person, how to log into jBPM5?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What do you mean, I'm not a good person? ;)

If you use the installer, that is one of the users that is configured by default.
You can add your own users by editing the users.properties files and roles.properties files in jbpm-installer/auth (like [here](https://github.com/krisv/jbpm/tree/master/jbpm-installer/auth)) and rerun the installer.  They are copied to jbpm-installer/jboss-*/server/default/conf and specify login information for your application.

Comment: sorry, I just spend the whole day trying to use the installer and I'm a little PO :) First I had problem with proxy(with pwd) and than it started downloading everything VERY slow(eclipse 37MB took at least 1h) and than .... but I got it working :)