# Adding new user for jbpm-console access

Tags: console, jbpm, kie

I downloaded the source code for the full final installation of JBPM version 6.0.0.  I was able to build the source with the ant build tool from within the jbpm_install directory using the command "ant install.demo".  Jboss starts up fine and I am able to bring up the KIE Workbench signon page via the http://localhost:8080/jbpm-console URL.  I cannot log in though.  I'm familar with the add-user.sh script and tried adding a new user this way with the kie-server role, but no luck.  I also fooled with the Jboss related user/role config files within the jbpm_install/jboss... directory, then rebuilt and redeployed, but still no luck.  Right now I'm just using the default h2 database.  Any help or direction is appreciated.

Comment: I found this suggestion on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180639/how-to-login-as-krisv-in-jbpm5 I tried this but it didn't seem to correct my issue, I will try this solution again and post an update if I get pass the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have the right role. *kie-server* is a role for a user who connects to KIE Server through remote APIs. In order to log into the jBPM Console (or KIE Workbench), you need to have a user with one of these roles: ***admin***, ***developer***, ***analyst***, ***manager*** or ***user***. Look at section [9.4. Configuration](http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/6.4.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html/ch09.html#wb.Configuration) of the jBPM documentation.

And if I may suggest, try to use the latest version ***6.4.0.Final***. The version you are using is really old and full of bugs.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  This assistance helped me correct the issue.

Comment: To help someone in the future: In order to add users you need to execute jbpm-installer\wildfly-*.*.*.Final\bin\add-user.sh (or add-user.bat) and follow the instructions.